# is it possible to upload audio to twitter using update_with_media in node.js?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I have found some examples using images (ie https://gist.github.com/adaline/7363853), but does anyone know if it is also possible to upload media such as audio mp3 files and include the in_reply_to_status_id?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media-multiple-photos) you'll see that they **only** allow photos / images to be *uploaded*.

> Currently, the only type exposed in our entities is photo.

If you want to embed audio with your tweet, you will need to set up [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview).  The audio will need to be hosted on your site (or a site like SoundCloud).

Look specifically at the [Player Card](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/player).

Comment: I did read that, but you never really know, maybe there is a way round it! I don't think the Twitter cards will allow different custom audio for each tweet unfortunately

Comment: They will. A card just points to a URL. As long as you use different URLs, each with their own audio, you should be fine.

Comment: twitter bots cant really use this technique too much varied output

Comment: As long as your bot can also generate & upload an HTML page, it's perfectly possible.

Comment: So lets say you make a twitter bot that speaks your tweet back to you. For each tweet you receive you will have to create a new web page with the specific audio for that request and create a card that links to this page. Say your bot gets really popular, you have to keep all these pages and their audio files hanging around on your server in case the card is clicked (and delete them at some point), sure it's possible, but a bit impractical.